# Import an XML file and insert data into SQLite database in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, sqlite, ndbunit

I have generated an XML file by exporting my SQLite database in c#.net.My generated XML is like-

```
<root>
   <name1>
      <names>
         <id>5</id>           
         <from>Germany</from>
         <to>France</to>
         <through>
            <via>
                 <id>7</id>
                 <routeNo>5<routeNo>
                 <route>Vienna<route>
             </via>
         </through>           
     </names>
     <names>
         <id>10</id>           
         <from>US</from>
         <to>Canada</to>
         <through>
            <via>
                 <id>8</id>
                 <routeNo>10<routeNo>
                 <route>Mexico<route>
             </via>
         </through>           
     </names>
   </name1>
</root>
```

I am trying to import this XML file and insert all the data back into an empty SQLite database. I need to verify the contents before inserting into SQLite database. I have created an XSD file from my existing XML file.i used NDbUnit library here. My codes for importing the data from  the XML into SQLite database are following -

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=emptyDB.sqlite;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;";
        NDbUnit.Core.INDbUnitTest Database = new NDbUnit.Core.SqlClient.SqlDbUnitTest(connectionString);

        Database.ReadXmlSchema("myFlatXml.xsd");
        Database.ReadXml("myFlatXml.xml");    

        Database.PerformDbOperation(NDbUnit.Core.DbOperationFlag.CleanInsertIdentity);
```

I have used XSD file which is generated from XML file, but it seems, I have to create the XSD from my sqlite database. the problem is sqlite manager does not support exporting database to XSD file. Moreover, i can't find any clear documentation for crating the XSD using NDbUnit. Could anyone help please ?

Comment: The xml format is kinda weird, how you expect that xml be mapped to SQLite? destination table format, and which tag will be stored in which column?

Comment: I have generated this XML from a SQLIte database in c# as well. now i need to get back those data from XML to SQLite (empty database). Yes, this XML is a bit complicated. I am new in c#. could you please give me any hints how to that ?

Comment: Try to post your SQLite table schema and also c# codes used to generate that xml from SQLite table if possible. Coding logic to restore that xml back to database based on -reversed- logic you used to generate the xml might be easier then coding it from scratch. From current information only, I can't help further

Comment: I have edited the post and given the codes of exporting the data from sqlite to xml. is it enough to understand my problem ? i badly need to solve it.please help me.

Comment: It's not clear what the `root` variable in your code refers to. Can you post the code where you declare and initialize it, preferably including the bits used to load the data from SQLite in the first place?

Comment: you mean the XmlNode rootNode ?

Comment: codes for loading database are in different file. private SQLiteConnection connection;#region Constructors
        public root(){
            connection = new SQLiteConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;";
            connection.Open();
            createRootTables();}
        public void newRoot(String filepath){
            // Test SQL
            string dataSource = filepath;
            connection = new SQLiteConnection();            connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + dataSource;connection.Open(); createRootTables();}

Comment: it is instantiated in the constructor.

Comment: is my problem clear to you now ? please let me know if you need further clarification. i badly need to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [NDbUnit](https://code.google.com/p/ndbunit/) framework does exactly what you need. So no need to get your hands dirty.
Also available via NuGet.

Comment: While it's right that NDbUnit is made with unit testing in mind, it's in no way restricted to only that. You can easily use it for your scenario as well.

Comment: could you show me some example please ?i do not have much time, that's why, i am bothering you :(

Comment: And I have the time to do your work? I pointed you to the right direction, the rest is up to you...

Comment: ok, again. I need to get back the XML data into my empty database. before inserting the data, i need to check those data. i am following these steps- http://code.google.com/p/ndbunit/wiki/QuickStartGuide. is that what you recommend me to follow ?

Comment: Yep. Except that the QuickStart deals with testing. But it gives a good overall picture of how it all works.

Comment: i am creating an .xsd file from my existing xml file (step 1), doing it in visual studio. then, i am using these codes- string connectionString = "MyDatabase;"; NDbUnit.Core.INDbUnitTest mySqlDatabase = new NDbUnit.Core.SqlClient.SqlDbUnitTest(connectionString);mySqlDatabase.ReadXmlSchema(@"MyDataset.xsd");mySqlDatabase.ReadXml(@"MyXML.xml");mySqlDatabase.PerformDbOperation(NDbUnit.Core.DbOperationFlag.CleanInsertIdentity);CustomerRepository repository = new CustomerRepository();Assert.AreEqual(2, repository.GetAllCustomers().Count);  am i in right direction ? sorry for bothering you :(

Comment: i can't find which methods i have to use after loading the xml and xsd file. could you please tell me which methods i have to use to verify the contents and insert all the data into data tables ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'flat'? You need to generate an xsd from your db schema, then validate any xml against this xsd. If it doesn't validate, it won't work...

Comment: i mean if the XML is like <apple id="1" name="Apple 1">
      <orange id="5" orangeNmae="C1" function="good for health" part="7">        
        <banana id="9" bananaName="48" effect="23" notes="be careful" />
        <banana id="10" bananaName="49" effect="24" notes="be careful" />        
      </orange>
</apple>

Comment: that's all the attributes are in parameter.

Comment: Again: If it validates against the xsd, then it will pass, otherwise not. That's all there is to say...

Comment: i am using the following codes- string connectionString = "Data Source=database.sqlite;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;";
            NDbUnit.Core.INDbUnitTest Database = new NDbUnit.Core.SqlClient.SqlDbUnitTest(connectionString);

            Database.ReadXmlSchema("myXML.xsd");
            Database.ReadXml("myInputXML.xml");

            DataSet dataSet = new FlatXmlDataSet(new FileInputStream("myInputXML.xml"));
            Database.PerformDbOperation(NDbUnit.Core.DbOperationFlag.CleanInsertIdentity);

Comment: if i generate XSD file from existing XML file, will it work ? thank you again for your patience :)

Comment: No (or at least only accidentally). Not the XML is your primary source but your db schema.

Comment: the problem is the sqlite manager does not support export to XSD from database. visual studio also does not support creating XSD from database. do i need to create the XSD manually ?

Comment: i can't find any clear documentation here. could you please give me any link for a clear guideline ?

Comment: is it the right way ?  http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2009/11/23/new-version-of-ndbunit-released-support-for-sqlite-in-memory-db/

Comment: thank you so much. it is working now. now i need to improve it. now, it is working for importing XML data like- <names>
<id>5</id>  <from>Germany</from> <to>France</to><through>          
<id>7</id> <routeNo>5<routeNo>      <route>Vienna<route>           </through>  </names>. if i want to import flat XML data like - <names id="5" from="Germany" to="France"> <through id="9" routeNo="5" route="Vienna" /> <through id="10" routeNo="5" route="russia" /> </names> . in this case, it is showing format errors. could you please give me any hints about how to modify it ?